# How do you run T-SQL commands on multiple servers from one place?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some daily and weekly tasks where I run a script to get the required information.  What is the way to running this code once and hitting all the servers without having to log into each one of them separately?

Comment: What does your script specifically do?  That may allow us to get more specific with a recommendation.

Comment: One script is to cycle the logs and another is gather information of automated jobs and maintenance plans.

Comment: Are you trying to automate this? Or just looking for an easier way to run it?

Comment: Wasn't even thinking of automating, I guess I could create something in SSIS.  If i did that, would I still use CMS somehow?  My SSIS is limited, but I've been working with it a lot these past few months.  If I don't automate, yes, I'm looking for the easiest and least time consuming way.

Comment: @SeanPerkins I asked about automation because I am very close to launching a new product (it will have a Free version) that makes automating this type of stuff incredibly easy. It allows for dynamic discovery of databases, collects all output (i.e. your collecting job and maintenance plan info) to a single table for easy secondary processing (unlike a text file), and can pull a list of servers from a CMS (it might even be the only tool that can source a list of servers from a CMS). If you would like to be a beta tester, please contact me via the website listed in my profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this, but natively it sounds like [Central Management Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126.aspx) is a pretty good fit for you.

If it is just "one" script and "one" functionality to pull the information, consider writing a quick PowerShell script that loops through all of your servers (the list of servers can be contained in a text file or a database table, etc.) and executes the script.  This is quite simple and painless.

It all depends on how often your script(s) will change and what your comfort level is with each of the different approaches.

Comment: You can also use SQLCMD mode and `:CONNECT` depending on how complex and ad hoc the scripts are. There are also software tools like [multi-script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/) if you don't want to get your hands that dirty.

Comment: By configuring CMS, will this cause any extra resource usage on the designated server?  Or will it result in resource usage during the time of the script execution?

Comment: @SeanPerkins No, the designation is purely for holding the registered server information in a central location. SSMS does all of the work under the covers. The CMS instance designation is purely informational.